# Cannot migrate a project on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am trying to migrate a project on digital ocean using unbuntu.

On my local machine everything works fine, but when I tried to migrate on my server it appears that python give me syntax error for sign like (").

For example

```
messages.success(request, _(f"Your image has been successfully uploaded!**"**))
```

It does not take the coma...

How can I bypass that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using fstring which works on python3.6 and later version. My Ubuntu has python3.5 by default which doesn't know what the fstring is. Ensure that you've python3.6 or later else do not use fstring.